# Knowing which instance of a symbol the event listener came from?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I need some help! I have no doubt this is a dumb problem that I've just over-thought to the point I got dumb about it.

I've got one "main" instance of a MovieClip symbol (let's call it Mountain) with an accompanying class. In the flow of the program, I automatically generate 8 other instances of the same symbol, let's say, each has a different fill color. When i click one of those automatically generated ones, I wanted the main instance to change color to whatever color the automatically generated one was.

So after dynamically generating the item in a different class, I added an eventListener for MouseClick

```
var thisMountain=new Mountain; 
thisMountain.ChangeColor();
thisMountain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
this.addChild(thisMountain);
```

But that's when I realized that the eventListener had no way to tell the function it's calling, WHICH instance of the symbol was clicked on. So I went and added the event listener into the "Mountain" class, but then it's being called even when the main one is clicked on. So I added a boolean when the instance is created to differentiate, but that seems like awful awful coding.

So what should I do? Is that example clear? Should I just make yet ANOTHER class that extends the mountain class or something? What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Make sure you use currentTarget through these examples. The target can sometimes reference alternative items and can cause you odd problems later on. Uber seriously.

Comment: +1... Figured that out about 20 minutes after plugging in the answer. currentTarget no matter what from here out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
item1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
item2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
item3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
...
...
function itemClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
 trace((e.currentTarget as MyInstances).myColor);
}
```

but if you were creating the items in a separate class and didn't know the instance, or how many were created etc. etc. You might like to look into 'Custom Events'. Your items when clicked would fire off an event something like the following.

```
var myItemClickedEvt:MyCustomEvent = new MyCustomeEvent("itemClicked", myColor);
```

You could then listen for the "itemClicked" event and then doing something like:

```
function itemClicked(e:MyCustomeEvent):void{
     trace(e.myColor);
}
```

... but I'm probably just confusing the situation... you probably just need:

```
(e.currentTarget as MyInstances).myColor
```

Comment: God y'all all had the same answer, and that was "you never knew about "currentTarget", moron!!! Sorry I could only choose one answer or I'd have clicked 'em all. Thanks a lot y'all

Answer (score 2):

just  add an id variable to your mountain class:

```
var thisMountain=new Mountain('id1'); 
thisMountain.ChangeColor();
thisMountain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
this.addChild(thisMountain);
function itemClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace((e.currentTarget as Mountain).id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your scenario, but why couldn't you just use the `event.target` property?  Is it not what you need?  Assuming that `Mountain` extended a `DisplayObject`, you should have a reference to the object in question.

Eg:

```
thisMountain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    // do something with evt.target;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a dumb problem, but luckily there's an easy solution:
Use the **target** property of the MouseEvent.
So your event handler would look something like this:

```
protected function itemClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var clickedMountain:Mountain = e.target as Mountain; // cast target as a Mountain
    var mountainColor:Color = clickedMountain.mountainColor;

    // do something here to set the color of the main mountain
}
```

Depending on how your Mountain clip is set up, you might need to use **currentTarget** instead of **target** to make sure you're getting the Mountain, and not one of its children.